# How can I render a Clippy with text using Radare?

Tags: radare

From the [Radare.Org Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/radareorg/posts/1580859762229608?__tn__=-R)

> Clippy is now available in r2!

But the link to `radare.tv` is broke. I was talking to someone else at the Walmart checkout aisle and they were telling me about this too. How can I use Clippy in Radare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clippy in Radare can be used with the `?E` command.

```
$ r2 -qc'?E Hello, Super User!' malloc://1K
 .--.     .--------------------.
 | _|_    |                    |
 | O O   <  Hello, Super User! |
 |  ||    |                    |
 | _:|    `--------------------'
 |   |
 `---'

$ r2 -qc'?E Hello, Super User!' malloc://1K
 .--.     .--------------------.
 | _|     |                    |
 | O O   <  Hello, Super User! |
 |  |  |  |                    |
 || | /   `--------------------'
 |`-'|
 `---'
```

Comment: Why are you repeating the code in your answer? Is showing the code once not enough for you?

Comment: In addition, you should provide a link to back up your answer.

Comment: @DavidPostill the two executions produce different output.